# Should one close Hibernate Session object every time after performing any CRUD operation?

Tags: spring

I am working with enterprise application that uses **Spring 3.x with Hibernate annotated programming**.I am working with hibernate `Session` object for performing db operations in my `XYZDaoImpl` class.

And my doubt is  "Is it correct way to close Hibernate `Session` object every time after performing any CRUD operation?"

If it is not the correct way, please advise me the recommended way of opening/closing of hibernate `Session` Object.

Answer (score 1):

can you post a bit daoImpl code......

If you use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, you will get current session..in this case framework automatically flushed and closed when the transaction ends (commit or rollback).

If you use `sessionFactory.openSession()`, you have to manage the session yourself and to flush and close it "manually".

Answer (score 1):

No, when using hibernate with spring, you should not (manually) open or close sessions, but let spring manage the hibernate session for you. Spring manages the session as a transactional resource, so you have to configure transaction management correctly.

If you open/close the hibernate session manually, you are hardly using the integration between these two frameworks: the session management is the main feature of the integration.

The only reason to open/close a hibernate session in a spring context is to use the same session to span multiple transactions.